# Theano undefined reference to dgemm (Windows 7, WinPython)

Tags: python, windows-7, theano

I use WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1 and Theano. Importing Theano works and I can even train a recurrent neural network. However, when I try to use a convolutional neural network I get the following error:

> [...]mod.cpp:528: undefined reference to `dgemm_'\r.[...]

I assume that some library is missing / not available for my CPU but I can't figure out how I can fix this. Could you tell me which information you need to help me debug this and finally solve this issue?

As an example, this code ([from a kaggle forum](https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/forums/t/13973/a-few-tips-to-install-theano-on-windows-64-bits?forumMessageId=98833)) works just fine:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import theano

print('blas.ldflags=', theano.config.blas.ldflags)

A = np.random.rand(1000, 10000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
B = np.random.rand(10000, 1000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
np_start = time.time()
AB = A.dot(B)
np_end = time.time()
X, Y = theano.tensor.matrices('XY')
mf = theano.function([X, Y], X.dot(Y))
t_start = time.time()
tAB = mf(A, B)
t_end = time.time()
print("NP time: %f[s], theano time: %f[s] (times should be close when run on CPU!)" % (
np_end - np_start, t_end - t_start))
print("Result difference: %f" % (np.abs(AB - tAB).max(), ))
```

The output:

```
blas.ldflags= 
NP time: 0.452026[s], theano time: 0.491028[s] (times should be close when run on CPU!)
Result difference: 0.000000
```

I am also receiving an error, every time I import theano but it never stopped my recurrent neural network from working. This is the error:

```
1 #define _CUDA_NDARRAY_C
2 
3 #include <Python.h>
4 #include <structmember.h>
5 #include "theano_mod_helper.h"
6 
7 #include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
8 #include <iostream>
9 
10 #include "cuda_ndarray.cuh"
11 
[...]
5327 
5328 /*
5329   Local Variables:
5330   mode:c++
5331   c-basic-offset:4
5332   c-file-style:"stroustrup"
5333   indent-tabs-mode:nil
5334   fill-column:79
5335   End:
5336 */
5337 // vim: filetype=cpp:expandtab:shiftwidth=4:tabstop=8:softtabstop=4:textwidth=79 :
5338 
===============================
nvcc : fatal error : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual Studio. Only the versions 2008, 2010, and 2012 are supported
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 4294967295, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -O3 -Xlinker /DEBUG -D HAVE_ROUND -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=mc72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD -IC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda -IC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -IC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\include -IC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof -o C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.5.1-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -LC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\libs -LC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64 -lpython35 -lcublas -lcudart')

['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '-Xlinker', '/DEBUG', '-D HAVE_ROUND', '-m64', '-Xcompiler', '-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=mc72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD', '-IC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda', '-IC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include', '-IC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\include', '-IC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.5.1-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd', 'mod.cu', '-LC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\libs', '-LC:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64', '-lpython35', '-lcublas', '-lcudart']
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572414/error-while-using-conv2dlayer-with-lasagne-neuralnet?rq=1) thread which talks about the same problem but it just links to another site. I can follow those instructions but they are assuming I don't use WinPython, installing everything from the beginning. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the empty theano.config.blas.ldflags. The documentation states that the default is -lblas and dgemm_ is a BLAS thing. Try installing a blas and setting this variable. 
E.g. for MKL:

1. Install MKL
2. Make sure your compiler can find mkl_rt by setting LIBRARY_PATH
3. set theano.config.blas.ldflags='-lmkl_rt'

Comment: Error:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmkl_rt

I set LIBRARY_PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2017.0.036\compilers_and_libraries_2017\windows\compiler\lib

Was that correct?

Comment: Does it have the libmkl_rt?

Comment: Ok, I fixed the path but now I get this new error:
Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Dot22(X, Y), '\n', 'Compilation failed (return status=1): C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2017/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_rt.lib: error adding symbols: No error\r. collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status\r. ', '[Dot22(X, Y)]')

Comment: what a helpful error message! I'm certain Winpython comes with some form of BLAS, you could try to find where that one is located and set your path and config.blas.ldflags accordingly.  np.__config__.show() may tell you the location of that BLAS library.